# toString won't show the expected result when displaying a node for a General Tree

Tags: java, data-structures

I am creating a program that is able to have users create a name for a task list that will function as a root for my tree. The problem is, when displaying the node it would result to something like this:

```
===============CREATING A NEW TASK===============
Enter the name of the Task: 
TaskOne
edu.slu.ds.RootTasks@76fb509a

edu.slu.ds.RootTasks@76fb509a
```

the second error should show "no children" as the user is just creating its root task.

I have created two methods that add the children nodes and display them once adding has been done. I have also had the toString that can return the data used with my display method:

Here is the code for the main program of creating tasks:

```
void CreateTask(){
    System.out.println("===============CREATING A NEW TASK===============");
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the Task: ");
    String entered = keyboard.nextLine();
    RootTasks task = new RootTasks(entered, null);
    TreeNode<RootTasks> rootTasksTree =new TreeNode<>(task);
    rootTasksTree.addChild(rootTasksTree);
    rootTasksTree.showChildren();

    System.out.println("Create a level one task Y/N?: ");
    switch (keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase()){
        case "Y":
            CreateLevelOneTask();
            break;
        case "N":
            run();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Choice");
    }
}
```

Here is my addChild and showChildren methods:

```
  public void addChild(TreeNode<T> testNode){
        if (firstChild == null) {
            setFirstChild(testNode);
        } else {
            TreeNode<T> pointer = firstChild;
            while (pointer.getSibling() != null){
                pointer = pointer.sibling;
            }
            pointer.setSibling(testNode);
        }
        testNode.setRoot(this);
    }



    public void showChildren(){
        System.out.println(this.toString() + "\n");
        if(firstChild == null){
            System.out.println("\tNo Branches");
        } else if (firstChild.sibling != null){
            TreeNode<T> pointer = firstChild;
            while (pointer.sibling != null) {
                pointer.showChildren();
                System.out.println();
                pointer = pointer.sibling;
            }
            pointer.showChildren();
        } else {
            System.out.println(firstChild.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getData() + "";
    }

}
```

The RootTask class will be used in creating the tasks at first and I've set the second parameter to null because that is where I will set its children nodes.

```
class RootTasks extends Tree{
private String title; //RootTasks title
private Tree<LevelOneTask> lvlOneTask;

public RootTasks(String title, Tree<LevelOneTask> lvlOneTask){
    this.title = title;
    this.lvlOneTask = lvlOneTask;

}

String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

void setTitle(){
    this.title = title;
}

public Tree<LevelOneTask> getLvlOneTask(){
    return lvlOneTask;
}

public void setLvlOneTask(Tree<LevelOneTask> lvlOneTask) {
    this.lvlOneTask = lvlOneTask;
}

public void displayTaskList(){
    try {
        System.out.println(getTitle());

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("No tasks of any found");
    }


}
```

The case below for LevelOneTasks works the same at the RootTasks except consisting more with title,description, its status (marked complete or not) and LevelTwoTasks which only consist of a title and its status.

I expect the output to be something like this:

```
===============CREATING A NEW TASK===============
Enter the name of the Task: 
TaskOne

Created Task:

TaskOne

    No Children Added
```

Comment: what does getData() return? output like that is when you don't have a (correct) implementation for toString()

Comment: `rootTasksTree.addChild(rootTasksTree)` You add the root as a child of itself? Why?

Comment: in which class did you define the `toString()`method?

Comment: @Stultuske getData simply returns data within my TreeNode class and I made the variable a type T.

Comment: @Andreas I added the root as a child of itself because I thought I needed to add it first before I can display it. Although I may have gotten the thought process wrong..

Comment: @P.J.Meisch the toString method is within my TreeNode class

Comment: and the object returned by `getData()`has a `toString()` method as well?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch yes, to my knowledge it does.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is the HashCode of the Object you're trying to print. You need to Override the toString() method of the Object you're trying to print. TreeNodes do have some getter-Methods though, like getUserObject().

The problem you're encountering stems from trying to call toString() on an Object of class Object, which like I said returns the HashCode of the Object instead of it's text value for example.